# How to convert a single char number like '5' into integer

Tags: c

How to convert a single character like `char c = '5'` into an `int`, like I can use the `c` that is converted into an `int` to do arithmetic calculation. Above I'm trying to make a simple program that you read from your keyboard a string like `'123+443'` and it's display the calculation between these 2 number 123+443 that is equal to 566.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char str[255];
int nr1 = 0;
int nr2 = 0;
int aux,i,j;
char semn;
int result;

int main(void)
{

    printf("insert your calculation \n");
    scanf("%s", str);

    for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if( (str[i]== '-') || (str[i]== '+') || (str[i]== '/') || (str[i]== '*') )
        {
            semn = str[i];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            aux = atoi(&str[i]);
            printf("convertirea nr1 = %d\n",aux);
            nr1 = nr1*10 + aux;
            printf("nr1 = %d\t ",nr1);
        }
    }


    j=i;


    for(i=j+1;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        aux = atoi(&str[i]);
        printf("convertirea nr2 = %d\n",aux);
        nr2 = nr2*aux;

        printf("nr2 = %d\t",nr2);
    }

    printf("\n--------------\n");
    printf("%d\n", nr1);
    printf("%d\n", nr2);
    printf("%c\n",semn);
    if(semn =='-') result = nr1 - nr2;
    if(semn =='+') result = nr1 + nr2;
    if(semn =='/') result = nr1 / nr2;
    if(semn =='*') result = nr1 * nr2;

    printf("%d\n",result);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` would not work, because it expects a null-terminated string. When you pass `&str[i]` to it, the function proceeds to parse the rest of the string. Only for the last digit in the string will it give you the answer that you expect.

To convert a character that represents a digit to the corresponding number, subtract `'0'` from it:

```
char c = '5';
int n = c - '0'; // n == 5
```

The reason this works is that the ASCII (and even [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) codes that represent digits occupy a consecutive range of numbers, with the code of digit zero `'0'` at its beginning and `'9'` at the end.

Comment: +1, but it would be a “+2” if you could add a sentence that explains that the digits are ordered in their “natural” order in the ASCII character set so subtracting the character code of `'0'` gives the offset from 0, hence the value.

Comment: @Deduplicator EBSDIC would work as well, because digits are mapped to a contiguous range `F0..F9`.

Comment: Note that this assumes that digits are consecutive and in order in the platform default locale, which is true in ASCII and Unicode, but not guaranteed by the ISO C standard.

Comment: @b4hand: It is specified. 0 to 9 are ascending and consecutive.

Comment: @b4hand  "... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous. ..." C11dr §5.2.1 3

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think you mean EBCDIC